# My Google Sheets API Console has duplicated pane

Tags: google-sheets-api

In my Google Sheets API Console, there are duplicated "Read/Write requests".

First "Read requests" has real data and has options "Read requests per day" and "Read requests per minute".

Second "Read requests" has no data and has options "Read requests per day" and "Read requests per 100 seconds".

Why does second pane exist?Is it just me?

Best regards.

[appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV2SS.png)

[First pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1MfS.png)

[Second pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri1pn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All newly created projects in GCP have the same quotas in Google Sheets API. This is the default set by Google:

[image]

The 100-second quota and 60-second quota are different entities.

If you want to request changes/increase to these default quotas, please follow the steps here:

**Increase the quota for an API**

Depending on your resource usage, you may want to increase the quota for an API.

1. Go to the Google Cloud Platform Console and sign in as a G Suite super administrator.
2. From the Project list, select the project you're using for the migration.
3. On the left, click IAM & admin and then Quotas.
4. Using the checkboxes, select one or more quotas to edit, then click Edit Quotas.
   Note: Billing must be enabled on the project in order to click the checkboxes.
5. In the Edit Quotas panel on the right, complete the form with your Name, Email, and Phone details, then click Next.
6. In the Edit Quotas panel, select the service to expand the view, then edit the quotas in that service to your requested limit. Click Done.
7. Click Submit request.

For more information, please check this support page: [Monitor API Quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6301355?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for response.
I have two more quetions.

(1) I don't understand why there are many entries actually the same limit.
And except for one of them, these entries are not tracked at all.
Why are they needed?

(2) If I want to increase the quota, do I have to become a G Suite user? 
Is it possible for normal Google users to change the quota?